# How to use base url or php variable in javascript file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am new in PHP, i want to use "base_url"(php variable) in javascript file,But right now i am unable to load image,Here is my current code,How can i do this ? Thanks in advance.

`$('#site-logo').find('img').attr( {src:'<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/images/logo/logo_dark@2x.png',width:'151',height:'45'} );`

Comment: Have you checked the value `base_url` returns? It should contain the trailing slash too. An easy way probably would be just a relative URL: `'/assets/images/logo/logo_dark@2x.png'`, no need for PHP.

Comment: @Teemu: actually i need to give "dynamic url" (base_url) which mentioned in "config.php" so thats why i want to use php variable,hope you understand my point

Comment: So what does the JavaScript code this generates actually look like? Did this piece of code even get sent through the PHP parser in the first place?

Comment: try to use "" for <?php tag and also concat that string to it also check if the final url generating is targetting the asset or not

Comment: @RohannnSingh can you please update my answer/write exact code so i can check and i can implement at my side

Answer (score 1):

You can create a variable or a constant in the javascript and store the base url there and use the same in the code.

Something along the line of following

```
var BASE_URL = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>";

$('#site-logo').find('img').attr({src: BASE_URL+'/assets/images/logo/logo_dark@2x.png',width:'151',height:'45'});
```

Comment: @Jigalk sorry but its not working

Comment: @Ritikamishra please try to check where are the assets file and then try to inspect and see what asset url is created at src 
Then compare both url are they same or not